# VBA Format Cells based on another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am needing to add a variable range, per row starting in G2 (always) and carrying through the lastrow/lastcol -4 and then subtracting the value in the D column for each row & entering that result in lastcol-3.  I've pieced this code together from other codes, and never used function.Sum, so I may be way off. 
 Here is what I currently have for my code:
[image: Current Code]

Comment: Please put the code in the Post as text and not a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lastcol` is a number not a letter and Range, when using strings, expects letters.

Change to Cells():

```
sht.Cells(i,lastcol-3).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(sht.Range(sht.Cells(i,7),sht.Cells(i,lastcol-4)))
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you and sorry for the original code format.